# connect to a mapped SQL server through PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working with an already built database on 2008 Server R2 platform, and am wanting to create an application to query said DB.

All of my experience is with local installs of MySQL, however this database is an MS SQL server 10.50.

My question is this, 
The SQL server is a mapped drive to the web server, I've got all proper PHP drivers and SQLsrv extensions installed and am getting proper phpinfo read outs, everything is functioning properly, but I am stumped as to how to connect to the SQL server. To clarify,

My application lives on the web server, I am wanting to connect via php to the SQL server which is mapped to the web server. I'm using windows authentication.

The connection PHP i have written so far looks like this

```
<?php
$serverName = "SmartCM.IMG"; 


$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"SMARTCM");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "I tried, but it didn't work out... sorry.<br /><br><br><br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

This is the error read out I get

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => 08001 
        [SQLSTATE] => 08001 
        [1] => 53 
        [code] => 53 
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. 
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => HYT00 
        [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 
        [1] => 0 
        [code] => 0 
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired 
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 08001 
        [SQLSTATE] => 08001 
        [1] => 53 
        [code] => 53 
        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. 
        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) 
    )
```

Comment: Check out this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746245/how-to-turn-mysql-strings-into-sql-server-equivalents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

You need to **enable Named Pipes**:

Open SQL Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols -> Named Pipes -> Right-click -> Restart

> A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

Use proper server and instance names (you need to determine both) for example `PC\SQLEXPRESS`.

Also check if **TCP/IP connection is enabled**:

Open SQL Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols -> TCP/IP -> Right-click -> Restart

Check if firewall is blocking a connection on port 1433.

Comment: great information, thanks! I was able to get named pipes open. I'm still having trouble getting the actual connection.. I've verified that the instance name should be MSSQLSERVER, however I'm stumped on the servername... I know that generally this should be localhost or an IP, but since I'm wanting to connect to a mapped drive I'm not sure... i'm not even sure if it's possible. I've tried the connection to the drive itself "\\WIND2k8R2-SQL" and the it's name "SmartCM.IMG". I've also tried the IP, but i figured this wouldn't work since the two machines share an external IP.

Comment: Try machine_name_of_pc_on_which_sql_is_running\SmartCM.IMG for example my pc name is 'mypc' and I run instance named 'test'. The name I should connect will be 'mypc\test'.

Comment: Seems I had the wrong IP address, I've now got a connection. Thanks!